# How to capture a screenshot of other iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am new to iOS development. I want to develop a screenshot application in iPhone and iPad. Is it possible in iOS. I want to capture screenshot of all application in iPhone. Is it legal to do so?

Thanks

Comment: All application screen shots from a single app?

Comment: I don't think the security model of iOS allows you to do so.

Comment: @Kanan Vora : yes, I want to take screenshot of the contents what is seen on screen. It will be triggered by pressing camera button or by shaking the screen.

Comment: You can capture creen shot of your own application thats what I know. As of I know there is no legal way to do like : Run your app and Capture screen shot of any other app.

Comment: Yes you can absolutely take screen shot of your app, but it is not possible to take screen shots of every app using a single app. Sorry!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is illegal, but the iOS app Display Recorder did it with a framework called [IOSurface](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/IOSurface), which manages a rectangular pixel buffer at the kernel level.  You will not be able to detect shake events at the kernel level, but you can record a fairly shaky stream with the pixel buffer and have the user select the appropriate image.

Comment: where can i get the iOS app Display Recorder

Comment: It was removed from the store.  It slipped by because IOSurface was an afterthought framework.